# How to get embedded Explorer IShellView to be browsable (i.e. trigger BrowseObject event)

Tags: windows, winapi, windows-explorer, windows-shell

i am "embedding Windows Explorer" in my Win32 application. (Technically i am hosting a [ShellView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774834%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) of a folder in my application, which is what Windows Explorer does).

The problem is that the view is never calling IShellBrowser.BrowseObject. Rather than asking *me* to navigate to a new location (through the BrowseObject event), the shell view is launching a copy of Windows Explorer to view the folder.

i want the default shell view (colloquially known as DefView) to be browsable.

---

### Sample code tutorial

First we need to get the [`IShellFolder`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775075%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for some folder that i want to display. The simplest folder to get is the Desktop folder, since there is an [`SHGetDesktopFolder API`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762175%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for it:

```
folder: IShellFolder;

SHGetDesktopFolder({out} folder);
```

Next we ask the desktop folder to [hand](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775064%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) us its [IShellView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774834%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

```
view: IShellView;

folder.CreateViewObject(Self.Handle, IID_IShellView, {out}view);
```

Now that we have the **IShellView** of the folder (as opposed to the **IContextMenu** or **IExtractIcon**), we now want to show the shell view by calling [IShellView.CreateViewWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774827%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

```
hostRect: TRect; //where the view is to display itself
folderSettings: TFolderSettings; //display settings for the view
hwndView: HWND; //the newly created view's window handle

folderSettings.ViewMode := FVM_DETAILS; //details mode please, rather than icon/list/etc
folderSettings.fFlags := 0;
hostRect := Rect(20, 20, 660, 500); //the view can position itself there

view.CreateViewWindow(nil, folderSettings, shellBrowser, {var}hostRect, {out}hView);
view.UIActivate(SVUIA_ACTIVATE_NOFOCUS);
```

et voila, the recognizable shell listview, showing my desktop:

[image]

complete with context menu handlers:

[image]

Except that when i click **Open**, rather than sending me a [`BrowseObject`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775113%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) event through the [`IShellBrowser`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775123%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) interface i supplied, it opens a new window:

[image]

The same happens when i double-click.

How can i get Microsoft's DefView to be browsable?

---

### **Update** ShellBrowser implementation

When creating an `IShellView` you must give it an object that implements `IShellBrowser`. This `ShellBrowser` object is how the view communicates back to the hosting container.

Of the 15 methods, i only look carefully at four - the rest can return `E_NOTIMPL` (which of course may be the problem):

```
{IShellBrowser}
```

- `BrowseObject(PCUIDLIST_RELATIVE pidl, UINT wFlags);`

  ```
    //Informs Windows Explorer to browse to another folder.
    //This is the notification i want!
    Result := BrowseToAnotherFolder(pidl, wFlags);
  ```
- `GetControlWindow(UINT id, HWND *lphwnd);`

  ```
    //Gets the window handle to a browser control.
    //Since i don't have a toolbar, tree, status or progress windows, return 0
    lphwnd := 0;
    Result := S_OK;
  ```
- `SendControlMsg(UINT id, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam, LRESULT *pret);`

  ```
    //Sends control messages to either the toolbar or the status bar in a Windows 
    //From MSDN: Notes to Implementers
    //    If your Windows Explorer does not have these controls, you can return E_NOTIMPL.
    Result := E_NOTIMPL;
  ```
- `GetViewStateStream(DWORD grfMode, IStream **ppStrm);`

  ```
    //Gets an IStream interface that can be used for storage of view-specific state information.
    Result := E_NOTIMPL; //i'm don't have a stream to give you
  ```
- `TranslateAcceleratorSB(LPMSG lpmsg, WORD wID);`

  ```
    //Translates accelerator keystrokes intended for the browser's frame 
    //    while the view is active.
    Result := E_NOTIMPL; //i won't be doing any translating
  ```
- `OnViewWindowActive(IShellView *ppshv);`

  ```
    //Called by the Shell view when the view window or one of its child 
    //    windows gets the focus or becomes active.
    Result := S_OK; //i got the notification, thanks
  ```
- `QueryActiveShellView(IShellView **ppshv);`

  ```
    //Retrieves the currently active (displayed) Shell view object.
    ppshv := view;
    Result := S_OK; //i would never view another, you know that
  ```
- `EnableModelessSB(BOOL fEnable);`

  ```
    //Tells Windows Explorer to enable or disable its modeless dialog boxes.
    Result := S_OK; //You want to enable modeless dialog boxes? Interesting.
  ```
- `InsertMenusSB(HMENU hmenuShared, LPOLEMENUGROUPWIDTHS lpMenuWidths);`

  ```
    //Allows the container to insert its menu groups into the composite
    //  menu that is displayed when an extended namespace is being viewed or used.
    Result := E_NOTIMPL; //i no has menus
  ```
- `RemoveMenusSB(HMENU hmenuShared);`

  ```
    //Permits the container to remove any of its menu elements 
    //   from the in-place composite menu and to free all associated resources.
    Result := E_NOTIMPL; //i no has menus
  ```
- `SetMenuSB(HMENU hmenuShared, HOLEMENU holemenuRes, HWND hwndActiveObject);`

  ```
    //Installs the composite menu in the view window.
    Result := E_NOTIMPL; //i no has menus
  ```
- `SetStatusTextSB`

  ```
    //Sets and displays status text about the in-place object 
    //in the container's frame-window status bar.
    Result := E_NOTIMPL; //i no has status bar
  ```
- `SetToolbarItems(LPTBBUTTONSB lpButtons, UINT nButtons, UINT uFlags);`

  ```
    //Adds toolbar items to Windows Explorer's toolbar.
    Result := E_NOTIMPL; //i no has toolbar
  ```

There's then the ancestor [`IOleWindow`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680102%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

- `GetWindow([out]  HWND *phwnd);`

  ```
    //Retrieves a handle to one of the windows participating in 
    //   in-place activation (frame, document, parent, or in-place object window).
    phwnd := Self.Handle; //here's the handle, again, of your parent
    Result := S_OK;
  ```
- `ContextSensitiveHelp([in]  BOOL fEnterMode);

  ```
    //Determines whether context-sensitive help mode should be entered 
    //during an in-place activation session.

    Result := S_OK; //Ok, thanks, i'll make a note of it
  ```

## IServiceProvider

```
function TShellBrowser.QueryService(const rsid, iid: TGuid; out Obj): HResult;
var
    sb: IShellBrowser;
    s: string;
const
    SID_SInPlaceBrowser: TGUID = '{1D2AE02B-3655-46CC-B63A-285988153BCA}';
    SID_IShellBrowser: TGUID = '{000214E2-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}';
begin
    {
        This code is executed when you double click a folder.
        It's needed to implement inline browsing.
        If you double click a folder the default action of IShellBrowser is to open a new Windows Explorer.
        To open the folder in the current window you must implement IServiceProvider.

        http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2009/12/30/windows-7-web-browser-control-will-not-browse-file-system.aspx
    }
    Result := E_NOINTERFACE; //Return $E_NOINTERFACE

    OutputDebugString(PChar('TShellBrowser.QueryService: '+IIDToString(rsid)));
    {
        Make a small change to your application to enable the filesystem object to navigate in-place within the WebOC
        when running on Windows 7.
        To do so, your hosting application will implement the IServiceProvider interface,
        and hand back the WebBrowser control’s SID_SShellBrowser when asked for SID_SInPlaceBrowser
    }
    if IsEqualGUID(rsid, SID_SInPlaceBrowser) then
    begin
        sb := Self as IShellBrowser;
        Pointer(Obj) := Pointer(sb);
        sb._AddRef;
        Result := S_OK;
    end;
end;
```

## Bonus Reading

- [ex-MSFT Eric Law documents this behavior as an instantional change in Windows 7, and how to work around it](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2009/12/30/windows-7-web-browser-control-will-not-browse-file-system.aspx). <sup>[archive](https://archive.ph/VeWXA)</sup> (Except it doesn't work)
- [fogbit having the same problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10277918/ishellbrowserbrowseobject-isnt-called)
- [more talk on how to implement IServiceProvider to respond to SID_SInPlaceBrowser](http://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/156616-implementing-windows-explorer-right-pane/)

---

### See also

- [Implementing IShellBrowser to host IShellView](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/shell/explorer.aspx?msg=972567)

Comment: The SDK shell samples have a couple of samples that embed explorer. I'd give those a quick once over.

Comment: If you can take a dependency on Windows Vista, the `IExplorerBrowser` interface makes this a lot easier.

Comment: @Ian Your life is now complete!

Comment: @DavidHeffernan i can't find a sample that embed's an `IShellView`, whether a standard view or a namespace extension. Can you point out the same's filename/folder? It's important to note that i'm not creating a namespace extension, but rather acting the part of Windows Explorer, or a common file dialog (i.e. *implementing* `IShellBrowser`, rather than *talking* to it).

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Yeah, i thought you'd like that. Bonus Chatter: i know i did.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On Vista or higher you can switch to hosting ExplorerBrowser, from which you can QI IObjectWithSite and pass an object that implements IServiceProvier with services like SID_SShellBrowser or SID_SInPlaceBrowser.

On XP you probably need to handle DDE messages originated from your process as the default folder association is DDE back then.

Comment: In the end i gave up trying to solve the problem. i switched to using `IExplorerBrowser` as suggested. i abandoned trying to host a `ShellBrower`, as just too hard. (Hell, if a shell team guy couldn't figure it out: what chance do i have.)

Answer (score 1):

Some missing code I used to reproduce this example.

```
TForm1 = class(TForm, IShellBrowser)
```

After that implement the `IShellBrowser` interface and get the `FShellBrowser` variable.

```
self.GetInterface(IID_IShellBrowser, FShellBrowser)
```

use `FShellBrowser` in:

```
FShellView.CreateViewWindow(FPreviousView, FFolderSettings, FShellBrowser, FHostRect, FViewHandle)
```

Clicking a directory only generates:

```
OnViewWindowActive

GetControlWindow
```

Another problem with this code is:
How to communicate to Explorer that the form is resized and you want to resize the hosted Explorer. 
Explorer browser has the `SetRect` method.

I agree use IExplorerBrowser.