# IShellBrowser::BrowseObject isn't called

Tags: c++, com, explorer, windows-shell

I'm trying to implement explorer-like frame in my application. This must work under WinXP too.

I've implemented `IShellBrowser` in my window-class + i've implemented `IUnknown` interface.

My class atributs:

```
IShellViewPtr m_shView;
HWND m_wndHolder;
CListViewCtrl  view;
```

Here is the code of `WM_CREATE` handler

```
m_hWndClient = view.Create(m_hWnd, rcDefault, NULL, 
            WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_CLIPSIBLINGS |
            WS_CLIPCHILDREN, WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE); // view isn't null after it

CMessageLoop* pLoop = _Module.GetMessageLoop();
        pLoop->AddMessageFilter(this);
        pLoop->AddIdleHandler(this);

IShellFolderPtr pParentFolder;
ATLVERIFY(SHGetDesktopFolder(&pParentFolder) == S_OK); // OK

FOLDERSETTINGS fs;
fs.fFlags = FVM_DETAILS;
fs.ViewMode = FVM_LIST;

ATLVERIFY(pParentFolder->CreateViewObject(view, IID_IShellView, (void**)&m_shView) == S_OK); // OK

RECT r; 
GetClientRect(&r);

ATLVERIFY(m_shView->CreateViewWindow(NULL, &fs, static_cast<IShellBrowser*>(this), &r, &m_wndHolder) == S_OK); // OK
ATLVERIFY(m_shView->UIActivate(SVUIA_ACTIVATE_NOFOCUS) == S_OK); // OK
```

After the application is started i have explorer-like frame in it.
I want to handle double click event in order to navigate through the folders in the frame. I expect that after double-clicking my implementation of `BrowseObject` will be called, but it doesn't happened. Instead of this folders are opened in system explorer.

Please help. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved the problem.

First you have to `IServiceProvider` interface if your class. Implementation should look like this:

```
QueryService( REFGUID guidService, REFIID riid, void __RPC_FAR *__RPC_FAR *ppvObject ) 
  {
    if (IID_IShellBrowser == riid)
    {
      *ppvObject = static_cast<IShellBrowser*>(this);
      AddRef();
      return S_OK;
    }

    *ppvObject = NULL;
    return E_NOINTERFACE;
  }
```

Also you have to add `IServiceProvider` support in your `QueryInterface` method.

```
STDMETHOD (QueryInterface)( REFIID riid,  __RPC__deref_out void __RPC_FAR *__RPC_FAR *ppvObject)
{
    if (!ppvObject)
        return E_POINTER;

    *ppvObject = NULL;

    if ( riid == IID_IShellBrowser )
        *ppvObject = static_cast<IShellBrowser*>(this);
    else if ( riid == IID_IUnknown )
        *ppvObject = static_cast<IUnknown*>(static_cast<IShellBrowser*>(this));

   else if ( riid == IID_IServiceProvider )
        *ppvObject = static_cast<IServiceProvider*>(this);

    if (*ppvObject)
    {
        AddRef();
        return S_OK;
    }
    return E_NOTIMPL;
}
```

After you'll inherit `IServiceProvider`, you can't cast you class to `IUnknown` using just `static_cast<IUnknown*>(this)`, so you need to write something like i did.

After that `BrowseObject` should be called fine.